# TSQL Geometry Query Requires conversion to string

Tags: sql, geometry, select

If I specifically define some polygons and check for containment, I get a correct result:

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
DECLARE @g2 geometry;

SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((407305 100826.5, 408725 100826.5, 408725 100217.5, 407305 100217.5, 407305 100826.5))', 0);

SET @g2 = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((408015.919 100522.86, 408016.749 100523.726, 408019.143 100526.225, 408019.309 100526.398, 408020.014 100527.134, 408020.327 100526.834, 408020.83 100526.352, 408022.23 100527.814, 408025.398 100531.121, 408026.392 100532.158, 408025.576 100532.94, 408031.013 100538.615, 408031.829 100537.834, 408037.246 100543.488, 408041.998 100538.936, 408040.849 100537.737, 408040.572 100537.448, 408042.32 100535.774, 408042.596 100536.063, 408045.817 100532.977, 408041.549 100528.522, 408042.365 100527.74, 408032.288 100517.222, 408030.59 100515.45, 408029.774 100516.232, 408025.326 100511.589, 408022.106 100514.674, 408022.382 100514.963, 408020.635 100516.637, 408020.358 100516.349, 408019.763 100515.727, 408018.936 100516.52, 408015.977 100519.355, 408015.012 100520.28, 408015.331 100520.613, 408016.735 100522.078, 408015.919 100522.86))', 0);

SELECT @g.STContains(@g2)
```

Attempting to do that in a query fails (returns no results)

```
SELECT geo.ogr_geometry
FROM spatial.dbo.[0] as geo
WHERE
(
    (@g.STContains(geo.ogr_geometry) = 1)
)
```

However, calling .ToString and converting that into a polygon returns the correct results:

```
SELECT geo.ogr_geometry
FROM spatial.dbo.[0] as geo
WHERE
(
    (@g.STContains(geometry::STGeomFromText(geo.ogr_geometry.ToString(), 0)) = 1)
)
```

Doing it like that is monstrously slow and seems ridiculous. What am I missing from the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Make sure that the SRID's in the geometries match.

The SQL [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.stcontains.aspx) states:

> STContains always returns null if the spatial reference IDs (SRIDs) of the SqlGeometry instances do not match.

And sure enough, I get null.

When I defined the polys I gave them an SRID of 0, so they matched and the query worked as expected.

In my second example I am selecting from a Table, the geometry instances contained in it have a different SRID.